# Biorthogonal (discrete wavelet) noise bases?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, wavelets

I am slightly interested in discrete wavelet transforms (DWT), but so far I have mostly used already-derived and existing well-known wavelets, such as Daubechies, Cohen-Daubechies-Faveau, Symlets and so on. As far as I know most existing wavelets tend to focus on one or a few of the following properties, compact support, orthogonality, symmetry and smoothness of wavelet function ("capturing" as many local differentiations as possible). In this question we limit ourselves to **biorthogonal discrete wavelets** which have the following constraints for the scaling sequences:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n{\tilde a}_{n+2m} = 2 \delta_{m,0}$$
and the wavelet sequences can then be expressed or determined as:
$$b_n = (-1)^n{\tilde a}_{M-n-1}\\ {\tilde b}_n = (-1)^n{a}_{M-n-1}\\s.t\\
n\in\{0,\cdots,N-1\}$$

---

Now to my question, would it be possible to create constraints to construct *noise* wavelets or *highly irregular* wavelets where the goal is to capture as much (additive) "unsmoothness" / "noise" as possible at every level. If possible, could they be useful? Any hints or references to such works are welcome as I am aware the question may be a bit too broad to answer completely.

---

**Own work:** By a crude and un-elegant optimization I have managed to get a few 4/4 tap wavelets with varying degrees of "smoothness". Here are two exampels.

[image]
Typical smooth 4/4 wavelet, a bit resemblant to [Daubechies 4 tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet#/media/File:Daubechies4-functions.svg) in looking kind of fractal-like, is it not?

[image]
Example of one particularly more "random" or un-smooth wavelet, once again a 4/4 biorthogonal. These are the kinds I am curious about, since they almost never appear in the literature. How to build them, analyze them and potential uses.

Comment: changing the mother wavelet doesn't change that the wavelet transform is a filterbank, so I don't see how you can hope "capturing as much (additive) unsmoothness / noise as possible at every level" : if it existed a linear operator capable of extracting the noise from signals that would be known. obviously, such an operator should be highly non-linear (maybe designing the wavelet specially for the signal we want analyze is not a bad idea)

Comment: designing the  filter specially for the signal we want analyze being the main idea behind linear prediction, which allows decorrelation/de-noising/compression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictive_coding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-excited_linear_prediction

Comment: If the above constraints are satisfied we will indeed be able to make a perfect reconstruction filter bank if we (re-)design mother wavelet and father wavelet differently. I have read a bit about linear predictive coding but it was ages ago. Thank you!

Comment: the wavelet transform doesn't require the biorthogonality criterion (which allows decimation of the signal at each stage of the filter bank, so it allows FAST wavelet transform, $\mathcal{O}(n \ln n)$ as the FFT) : it you don't decimate at each stage, any filter is usable in the wavelet transform, and this is what let us know that the wavelet transform is nothing more than a filterbank transform ( a bank of $k$ filters whose sum is the dirac $\delta(n)$), exactly as the short-time-Fourier-transform

Comment: the only difference being the bandwidths of those $k$ filters : linearly spaced for the STFT and logarithmically spaced for the wavelet transform (as for the constant-Q transform)

Comment: Yes you are right. I was aiming for filters which one can use fast transforms with filter banks (maybe I should add that to the question if it is unclear?). The STFT / FFT is fast because sines and cosines have these nice addition formulas which can be combined systematically to create $\log(n)$ factors to give this $n\log(n)$ complexity. But it is starting to be quite a discussion here in the comments :)